# Vectors vs ndarrays in pandas/numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, math, numpy-ndarray

I know for a 4D vector, shape should be (4, 1) which is actually represented in 4D space but ndim is 2, and for some ndarray to be in 4 dimension, its shape should be something like (2, 3, 4, 5).

So, Is it like dimensional concept differs between vector and matrices (or arrays)? I'm trying to understand from mathematical perspective and how it's derived to pandas programming.

Comment: When we say `2D` array, we actually refer to the shape of the array, not the data inside it. So a (2,2)-array also represent 4D data, but in a 2D shape (square). And relate to that, a (4,1)-array would also be a 2D array. A vector is normally just (4,).

Comment: A point in a 3d vector space can be specified by 3 numbers (likewise 2d (plane) or 4d with time).  But that's different from the `ndim` dimensions of a numpy array.  Don't confuse the two notions of dimensionality.  The array dimensions are more like the (all) the points in a Cartesian space (1,2,3, dimensions).

Comment: People coming from a linear algebra (or MATLAB) background are used to dealing with 2d arrays/matrices.  They think of `vectors` as row vectors (1,n) shape, or column vectors (n,1) shape, and often are confused by a 1d arrays, (n,) shape (that's a 1 element tuple).  1d arrays are more like the set of points that define a point in n-dimensional space, a 'vector' in the physics sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, arrays represents just a collection of points where as vectors of shape (n, ) are actual vectors in physical sense. correct?

Comment: Not necessarily.  A point in physical space might be represented as a 1d array.  A 1000 points as a 2d (1000,3) array.  Images often are 3d (height, width, color), and 1000 images as (1000, height, width, color) (4d).  Mapping arrays to the application can take many forms.  `pandas` mostly represents "tables", or "time series".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensionality of a mathematical object is usually determined by the number of independent parameters in that particular object. For example, a 4-D *vector* is mathematically 4 dimensional because it contains 4 independent elements (unless some relation between them has been specified). Such a vector, if represented as a column vector in `numpy`, would have a shape *(4, 1)* because it has 4 rows and 1 column. The transpose of this vector, a row vector, has shape *(4, )* because it has 4 columns and only 1 row, and the row-style view is default, so if there is 1 row, it's not explicitly mentioned.
Note however, that the column vector and row vector are *dimensionally equivalent* mathematically. Both have 4 dimensions.
For a *3 x 3* matrix, the most general mathematical dimension is *9*, because it has 9 independent elements in general. The shape of a corresponding `numpy` array would be *(3, 3)*. If you're looking for the maximum number of elements in any `numpy` array, `ndarray.size` is the way to go.

`ndarray.ndim`, however, yields the *number of axes* in a numpy array. That is, the number of *directions* along which values are placed (sloppy terminology!). So for the *3 x 3* matrix, `ndim` yields *2*. For an array of shape *(3, 7, 2, 1)*, `ndim` would yield 4. But, as we already discussed, the mathematical dimension would generally be *3 x 7 x 2 x 1 = 42* (So this is a matrix in 42-dimensional space! But the `numpy` array has just 4 dimensions). Thereby, as you might've already noticed, `ndarray.size` is just the product of the numbers in `ndarray.shape`.

Note that these are not just concepts of programming. We are used to saying "2-D matrices" in mathematics, but that is not to be confused with the space in which the matrices reside.